# Extracting (x,y) of cells overlapped with polyline in ArcGIS for Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst

I have a grid which is made up of 100*100 cells. I want each cell to be identified by its x (1 to 100) and y (1 to 100) value . For example the cell on the top left corner must be Identified as (1,1) and the cell on the bottom right corner be identified as  cell (100,100). There is a polyline which overlap some of these grid cells. I want to extract the (x,y) of each overlapped cell.

How can I do it in ArcMap?(Without python)

Answer (score 2):

This would be much easier to do using Python/ArcPy, but here is a ModelBuilder approach (with a Python snippet in field calculator)

Build a model that looks something like this:

[image]

The model uses the following tools.

- **Con** - set all raster cells to a single value
- **Raster to Polygon** - Converts raster extent to polygon
- **Get Raster Properties** - used to retrieve row count, column count, cell size, lower left corner coordinates.
- **Calculate Values** - creates an origin point using lower left coordinates. **Set Data Type to Point**. Output gets fed into Grid Index Features.

[image]

- **Grid Index Features** - creates a grid based on raster extent, column count, row count and lower left coordinates. Set polygon width/height to be the same as input raster cell size
- **Add Field** - Add two fields **CELL_ROW** and **CELL_COL** to the output from grid index features.
- **Calculate Field** - Calculates values for **CELL_ROW** and **CELL_COL**

Row and column positions are calculated using values from the **PageNumber** field generated by the Grid Index Features tool.

To get **cell row position**, divide **PageNumber** by the total number of rows then add 1, for rows where the PageNumber is not a multiple of total rows. Where PageNumber is a multiple of the total rows, cell row position is found by dividing the PageNumber by the row count. See graphic below.

[image]

**Cell column position** is given by PageNumber%column_count. if the modulus expression evaluates to zero, then cell column position = row_count.

[image]

The steps above yield (tested on a 100*100 grid, 1m cell size):

[image]

At this stage, you can plug in the rest of your processing steps. Use your polyline to select overlapping cells and take it from there..

Answer (score 0):

The number of possible solutions are somewhat limited without the use of Python. However, I'd suggest using the [Fishnet](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-fishnet.htm) function with polygons as output. Make sure that the fishnet cells covers the corresponding cell in your grid (this can take a few trials while creating the fishnet).

You now need to enumerate your polygons. Copypaste values from excel in an edit session to get the 1-100 in a field in the attribute table. Selection via the GUI is probably a good help here. However, some manual checking/value entering can probably not be avoided if Python is out of the question.

When this is done you can easily convert your polygons to a grid if need be, or just use it as a vector layer and query as is.

In fact, using it in vector format is probably easier. A spatial join between your polylines and these fishnet polygons should get you an attribute table field populated with the overlapping polygons' IDs.